# Installing Casper; a program that needs to be placed in a directory on my PATH

Tags: macos, terminal, install, software, path

I need to install software but I don't understand how to do so.
I have downloaded a file which contains 5 files which includes a
Unix Executable file which when I open displays this:

```
Last login: Tue Jul 19 14:07:37 on ttys001
laurens-MacBook:~ Lauren$ /Users/Lauren/Documents/casper-2.1/casper-1 ; exit;
/Users/Lauren/Documents/casper-2.1/casper-1: binary file /usr/bin not found
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

One of the files describes how to install the program..but I don't understand how to interpret these instructions...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

> Installation Instructions for Casper
>   2/09/2009
>
> To install Casper the entire contents of this directory should be
>   placed somewhere on your filesystem. Then, the file casper should be
>   edited such that CASPERBASE points to this directory. Lastly, the
>   edited casper should be placed in a directory that is on your PATH.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the installation instructions and describe the steps you did between downloading the file and getting to the part displayed in the terminal output?

Comment: http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/gavin.lowe/Security/Casper/

Comment: After I downloaded the file, I used a program to extract the file which I then saved in my Documents folder. I then simply clicked on the executable which displayed what I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the *casper-2.1-release.tar.gz* file would not extract successfully for me using the normal default OS X way and I tried three other and different methods. I was able to extract the contents however I had to set the `casper` file to executable after the extraction with the one method that successfully extracted all files. The other normal and default OS X method failed to extract beyond the *casper-2.1-release.tar* tar-ball. IMO There is something wrong with the *casper-2.1-release.tar.gz* archive file.

The picture below shows the line in the `casper` *bash script* executable that the "*Then, the file casper should be edited such that CASPERBASE points to this directory.*" is referring to.

Line 19 is where you set `CASPERBASE=` to `CASPERBASE=${path_to_casper_directory}`, e.g.:

```
CASPERBASE=${$HOME/casper-2.1}
```

As I extracted the archive to my Home Folder.

---

[image]

---

Then for the part of the install instructions "*Lastly, the edited casper should be placed in a directory that is on your PATH.*" I then edited my `̃/.bash_profile` file, and added the `$HOME/casper-2.1` directory to my `$PATH`, e.g:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/casper-2.1
```

I then closed Terminal and reopened it for the change to take effect.

---

Note the picture below is showing the contents of the *casper-2.1-release.tar.gz* file in Pacifist however it could not extract the highlighted *casper* file, while it did extract the other files.  I had to use [Zipeg](http://www.zipeg.com) to extract all files but had to set the `casper` file to executable after the extraction, using `chmod u+x casper` while in the `casper-2.1` directory in Terminal.

[image]

Comment: Firstly thankyou so much for looking into this! Unfortunately I don't understand how you got that screen though!

Comment: @ellefc, I opened the `casper` file in an editor, Sublime Text 2.  You can open it in any text editor.

Comment: so am I right in thinking all I need to do is write those 3 lines of code ie line 14, line 19 and then edit /.bash_profile, close the terminal, restart it and type casper to execute?

Comment: @ellefc, As a side note, the _casper-2.1-release.tar.gz_ file extracted complete and without reporting an error under Linux Mint 17.2 using the native Extract Here command from the context menu in Files. Don't know why any of the default and native OS X (10.8.5) methods wouldn't work much less several third-party apps.

Comment: @ellefc, As the comment line in the `casper` _bash executable_ says "_A simple shell script to invoke the Haskell interpreter and load in the 
Casper files._" is what the _script_ does.  Any relevant _variables_ in the _script_ should point to the appropriate location.  As I do not use Haskel and therefore cannot test any of this, I can only present what I did as if I was going to use it and what I do in similar cases with things such as this when it needs to be done. :)